# Copy data from Excel, paste to .txt file

Tags: excel, vba, utf

I am trying to figure out how to copy a range in Excel and paste to a .txt file. Note: This involves multiple languages which adds complications.

I currently have the following for copying the exact data range that I need, which works flawlessly. Think of it as a file tag modifier. Cell D19 is where I paste a list of file names. Col E~Z are where file tags reside (e.g. date created, modified). Col A is a concatenation of all data in col E~Z. A=E&";"&F&";"&G&";"&... So I get "E;F;G;..." One row per file.

```
Sub CopyTags()
    If Range("D19") = ""
    Then
        MsgBox "No tags to copy."
        'If D19 is blank, then there are no file names pasted = no tags to copy.
        
    Else
        Range("D19").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select   'Jump to the end of the list from D19.
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select.  'Jump to the left (from col D to col A where concatenated tags are).
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select   'Select everything from above (ctrl+shift+up).
        Selection.Copy
    
    End If
End Sub
```

My current process is - after copying the tags, I would then manually open a .txt file and paste the copied data (overwriting everything. The .txt file is then sent to a different program.

Now I am trying to expand on this by automating the pasting step to the .txt file. The following is what I have so far.

```
Sub WriteTextFile()
    Dim Path As String
        Path = "/Users/xyz/xyz/TagsUpdater.txt"

    Dim iLastRow As Long
        iLastRow = 78
        ' Simplified for now - 78 is the last row of my processor; ideally, I want to print only the necessary rows.

    Open Path For Output As #1
        For i = 19 To iLastRow ' 19 as in A19/D19 - the first row of data.
            Print #1, Cells(i, 1)
            Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

This actually works perfectly. However, my file names / file tags can have characters of different languages, so in my output .txt file, I see a bunch of _'s.

The simplest method I could think of is feeding the results of CopyTags() to a string, and then pasting the string to the .txt file. Though I'm not sure if this would bypass the language coding problem.

Or, copying the tags into a different tab within Excel, and then printing that tab to a .txt file.

Note: I am using a Mac with Office 365, so might have some complications with using SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your Q, but use of `Select` is a bad idea.

Better to set a reference and use that

Something like

```vb
Sub CopyTags()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D19") = vbNullString 
    Then
        MsgBox "No tags to copy."
        'If D19 is blank, then there are no file names pasted = no tags to copy.
        
    Else
        With Range("D19")
            Set rng = Range(.End(xlDown), .End(xlToLeft))
        End With
        WriteTextFile(rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

And change `WriteTextFile()` to accept a range parameter

```vb
Sub WriteTextFile(rng As Range)
    Dim Path As String
    Dim i As Long
    Path = "/Users/xyz/xyz/TagsUpdater.txt"

    Open Path For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
        Print #1, rng.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

FYI.

1. look into FreeFile (rather than assuming file handle 1 is available)
2. Look into Environ to get the User path
3. Consider if rng has more than 1 column